# How to replace a function on a Liferay native portlet

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I am making a change to a native Liferay portlet, that comes with Liferay Intallation. How can I change a function to my own implementation by a hook or similar approach?

I have read how to make pre and post conditions and how to make new implementation of an interface, but I don't know how to just replace random function inside random class at a portlet that I want to keep otherwise as it is originally.

Comment: I found [some help](http://liferay1.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/snippet/portal-devt/16-extending-liferay-table.txt) to my pain. Reading it through and looking if it helps..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are several ways you can modify the functionality of a native Liferay portlet. Here is a quick overview.

Most hooked functionality is described through the liferay-hook.xml file located in your /docroot/WEB-INF directory. Here are the most common method.

## [Custom JSPs](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Hook+DTD+-+6.0#section-Portal+Hook+Plugins-JSPs)

In the liferay-hook.xml file, add the following child to `<hook/>`

```xml
<custom-jsp-dir>/META-INF/custom_jsps</custom-jsp-dir>
```

This element defines the location of where you are going to place JSPs to be overwritten. For example you may want to rewrite view.jsp for the Document Library portlet at:

```
[custom-jsp-dir]/html/portlet/document_library/view.jsp
```

## [Model Listeners](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Hook+DTD+-+6.0#section-Portal+Hook+Plugins-Model+Listeners)

For this one you'll have to define a portal.property file typically stored at,

```
/docroot/WEB-INF/src/portal.property
```

And tell `liferay-hook.xml` its location. The following is an example for the above,

```
<portal-properties>portal.properties</portal-properties>
```

if you want to listen to changes in User, for example, you would write in the property,

```
value.object.listener.com.liferay.portal.model.User=com.my.example.UserListener;
```

Which is in the following format,

```
value.object.listener.[class-to-listen]=[my-listener-class]
```

And your class should implement `com.liferay.portal.model.BaseModelListener`.

Here you can listen to events such as Add, Update, Remove, and a few others.

## [Extend\Overwrite Service](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Hook+DTD+-+6.0#section-Portal+Hook+Plugins-Overriding+Services)

A similar story here, in `liferay-hook.xml` in the `<hook />` element add

```xml
<service>
    <service-type>com.liferay.portal.service.UserService</service-type>
    <service-impl>my.example.service.UserServiceImpl</service-impl>
</service>
```

Here your implementation should extend the correct wrapper class for a particular service. For the example above, for instance, is

```
com.liferay.portal.service.UserServiceWrapper;
```

You should now be able to overwrite all the public methods for the UserService like `updateUser(..)`.

## [Customization of Struts Actions](http://www.liferay.com/web/mika.koivisto/blog/-/blogs/overriding-and-adding-struts-actions-from-hook-plugins)

#### (Only available from Liferay 6.1 version)

In very similar fashion as extending services, define the elements for `<hook />`

```xml
<struts-action>
    <struts-action-path>/message_boards/view</struts-action-path>
    <struts-action-impl>my.example.action.SampleViewAction</struts-action-impl>
</struts-action>
```

You'll need to extend,

```
com.liferay.portal.kernel.struts.BaseStrutsAction
```

and you'll have access to the request and can perform a custom action. Which is very powerful in conjunction with custom JSPs.

#### Good Luck!

Be sure to check compatibility with the version of Liferay you are using.

If you need even more control you would need to use the ext-plugin.

Comment: @RP...hi....i want to add my own method into existing calendar portlet..here is my question and code...can u please look at it and let me know were i am doing wrong..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747253/adding-custom-methods-in-hook-environment