# Liferay page friendly URL generation URL

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

when I create a page in Liferay (I'm using 6.2) it receive an auto-generated friendly URL, following several internal rule.

So, for example, if I create a page named `aaa` it will automatically receive  `/aaa` friendly URL.

Also if I create the page "aaa" as a children of the page `xxx,` it will receive the same `/aaa` friendly URL.

For SEO issues, I need that will be created following a different pattern: `parent_friendlyURL + page_friendlyURL`.

This means that, if `xxx` parent page has `/xxx` friendly URL, its children `aaa` should have `/xxx/aaa` friendly URL, instead of just `/aaa`.

I searched for portal.properties options, but I don't find any solution to the problem.
Do you think a quick way exists to achieve this, or I have to do it by an hook?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked through `LayoutLocalServiceImpl.java` which gets auto-generated links from `LayoutLocalServiceHelper.java` should the user not pass in a `friendlyURL`.

So there are 2 approaches you can take.

1. You can simply edit the friendlyURL of your pages though the admin page.
2. You can write a hook to wrap the LayoutLocalService class and if the `friendlyURL` param is null or a blank string, write your own logic to generate the friendlyURL. If you're uncertain how, see this question: [How to replace a function on a Liferay native portlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872344/how-to-replace-a-function-on-a-liferay-native-portlet/6876755#6876755).

Comment: If using approach 2, it's  even easier to just extend Liferay's service wrapper, `LayoutLocalServiceWrapper`. [Check out the Liferay docs on that](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/overriding-a-portal-service-using-a-hook)

Comment: I don't believe you can without using an ext plugin and I would personally avoid having to use an EXT plugin.

Comment: Yes, before asking I have already seen helper class... by my question was if "there is a quick way, or should I use a hook?"... reading your answer it seems that hook is the only way. Thanks.

Comment: If someone else will follow this way, be aware to take care of already existing URL (duplicate url): LR manages them only in the case it also autogenerates friendlyURLs, otherwise it just validates URL format...